# What are the missable achievements in Memoria?

Tags: achievements, the-dark-eye-memoria

Which achievements in Memoria can be missed?  Are any of them mutually-exclusive?  How do I get them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep this spoiler-free.  Most of this is adapted from [here](http://www.adventure-zone.info/fusion/articles.php?article_id=1556) and [here](http://guides.gamepressure.com/memoria/guide.asp?ID=21587).

### Chapter 1

- **Getting the job done**: When asked, answer *"No, I don't like riddles."*  This will end the game.
- **Causing tremors**: Have the golem hit the 'Rock Face' 10 times.

### Chapter 2

- **Honesty is the best policy**: Tell Bryda the complete truth.

  > Choose the options "I don't know" - "It was behind the tent" - "Geron"
- **Crispy**: In the Inn, turn the pork-roast.
- **Master Detective**: In the Inn, accuse the right person for the right reason on the first try.

  > Accuse only Thorwalian, say he was not there *(don't mention the hangover)*
- **Nosebleed**:  Accuse the right person, but try to start a fight.

  > Accuse only Thorwalian, then talk about the hangover.

  You'll have to save and reload to get both **Nosebleed** and **Master Detective**.
- **Clumsy Oaf** / **Masterful Sneaker**: You get **Masterful Sneaker** for making it through to dormitory without getting caught, or **Clumsy Oaf** if you get caught.  To not get caught,

  > * Go all the way to the left and around the bed.
  >  * Go back to the farthest row of beds.
  >  * Go right to the shards, without stepping on them.
  >  * Cast a repair spell on the shards.
  >  * Cast the Magic Glow.
- **Baited**: Before leaving the dormitory, pick up the "Strange Artifact" next to the novice.  Give it to Bryda.
- **Firun's Disciple**: Catch the rabbit on the first try

  > * Spread the Pelt on the Flowery Meadow in the right-down corner.
  >  * Use the Dagger with Wooden Logs in the inventory and use the Wooden Stakes on the Pelt.
  >  * Take the Stakes out.
  >  * Use the Rope on the Pelt With Holes.
  >  * Use the Stick with the Tied-Up Pelt.
  >  * Now lay the Dandelion on the Flat Stone on the left, take another one and and lay it in front of the rabbit’s Hole further to the left.
  >  * Hide behind the Bushes With Rope’s End (you’ll have to click three times).

### Chapter 3

- **Phex Be With You**: From the start of the labyrinth, go Right, Middle, Right, Middle, Middle
- **The Journey's The Reward**: Get lost in the forest *(move areas 100 or so times)*

### Chapter 4

- **Doombringer**: Touch Owlric
- **Sadist**: Break and repair Owlric 10 times

### Chapter 5

- **Being Kind** / **Renegade**: Give the items to Xerxes / Throw them away.  You'll need to save and reload to get both.
- **A Knack of Spirits**: Convince the air spirit to help on the first try

  > Choose “Play with me!”, “Let’s play hide and seek!”, “You hide me from the magicians!”
- **Big Brother**: Adjust each horn to face the sphere above it *(on the first try?)*
- **Seek and Ye Shall Find**: At Satinav's piller *(the monolith)*, click in the middle of the wall on the left-side.

> [image: Satinav's piller]

### Chapter 6 and Chapter 7

*(No missable achievements)*

### Chapter 8

- **Finish Line** / **A Gift Called Freedom**:  Each of the final choices gives an achievement.  Save and reload to get both.